# Setting one cell's address equal to another...... In another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, cell, spreadsheet

Say I had just copied a table to another workbook, and wanted to write a macro to verify the copy was successful, I would have to have two range variables to compare them. How do I assign the address of the cell being compared to follow the other cell's address in the other workbook, so that they are both offset the same way, even if the two starting cells are different, and so can still be compared correctly?

Comment: not sure how specific you need it, or why exactly you need to verify it worked correctly, but how about the `Range.Rows.Count` and `Range.Columns.Count` properties? Are they useful to verify they are equal? You could also use the `.Cells` property of the '.Range' object. For example, `.Range("A1:A10").Cells(1,1)` versus `.Range("B1:B10").Cells(1,1)` will allow you to grab the upper left most cell of the 2 ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the originalRange to your original data range in the desired workbook. If this is run immediately after your paste you can use Selection for the pastedValue data. If not then change this accordingly:

```
Dim i As Double, j As Double
Dim originalRange() As Variant, pastedValue() As Variant
Dim copyPassed As Boolean

originalRange = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
pastedValue = Selection

copyPassed = True

For i = 1 To UBound(pastedValue, 1)

    For j = 1 To UBound(pastedValue, 2)

        If (originalRange(i, j) <> pastedValue(i, j)) Then

            copyPassed = False
            GoTo test_exit:

        End If

    Next j

Next i

test_exit:

MsgBox "Copy Passed: " & copyPassed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott and Philip for your replies! I've never seen the ubound function before, and shall read up on it now. And that would also be useful to check that the copied range was equal, thanks, didn't think of that.

Comment: Jean, Yesterday I tried using the count, to measure the difference from the two, and set the offset of the cell in the other table to the corresponding differences. But I found the code was too tedious. I actually wanted to know if there was a function to measure the address of a cell relative to a certain ref. pt.. so that if I used the for each...Next loop, it would run through all the cells in the first table, and the address of the variable in the other table would just offset suit. I had to leave during work on this problem, and so didn't see your replies until this morning.

Comment: [Ubound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f(v=vs.80).aspx) allows you to return the dimensions of your array. It is slow to loop through each cell on your speadsheet and so adding the data into arrays in VBA is very fast for comparing both datasets.

Comment: hmmm, I have an idea of why that is so, but would you mind explaining why to me? I'm very appreciative of the knowledge you've imparted so far.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly Philip, and you've caused me to go learn arrays in VBA, I've recently started learning the language, and am constantly looking for the next topic to learn. You've also shown me to know how each function affects processing and memory usage when compiled so that I know what logic is most efficient, no matter how small the task, Thank you. I also appreciate you asking me what I tried as your first question Jean, good time wasting reduction on your part!